# model.predict() returning the same value for all test cases of test_x

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am creating a model that classifies numbers between 0 and 10. I am facing a problem where all the predicted rows have the same value i.e. all rows of x_predicted are the same as you can see in the code below.

You can copy and paste the code in your code editor and try it.

```py
import numpy as np

from tensorflow import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.activations import softmax
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.losses import SparseCategoricalCrossentropy, CategoricalCrossentropy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.utils import to_categorical

(train_X, train_y), (test_X, test_y) = mnist.load_data()

train_y = to_categorical(train_y, num_classes=10)

train_X, train_y = np.asarray(train_X), np.asarray(train_y)

train_X = train_X.reshape([train_X.shape[0], train_X.shape[1] * train_X.shape[2]])
test_X = test_X.reshape([test_X.shape[0], test_X.shape[1] * test_X.shape[2]])

model  = Sequential(
    [
        Dense(units=25, activation="relu"),
        Dense(units=15, activation="relu"),
        Dense(units=10, activation="linear"),
    ]
)

model.compile(loss=CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), optimizer=Adam(0.01))

model.fit(train_X, train_y, epochs=3)

predicted_x = model.predict(test_X)
print(predicted_x)
```

this is the result of print(predicted_x):

```bash
[[ 0.07475024  0.21513198 -0.0613958  ...  0.05913167  0.04869198
  -0.03899333]
 [ 0.07475024  0.21513198 -0.0613958  ...  0.05913167  0.04869198
  -0.03899333]
 [ 0.07475024  0.21513198 -0.0613958  ...  0.05913167  0.04869198
  -0.03899333]
 ...
 [ 0.07475024  0.21513198 -0.0613958  ...  0.05913167  0.04869198
  -0.03899333]
 [ 0.07475024  0.21513198 -0.0613958  ...  0.05913167  0.04869198
  -0.03899333]
 [ 0.07475024  0.21513198 -0.0613958  ...  0.05913167  0.04869198
  -0.03899333]]
```

Comment: i've excuted the code that you provided on google collab and i got different results on each one (normal results)

Comment: @becem can you post a screenshot. I just ran the code on colab and I am getting the same results...

Comment: i'm sorry for my previous comment , i re-excuted the code right now and it had the same behaviour as you did, lowering the learning rate to 0.001 solved the problem, i'm no expert so i can't tell you why ( maybe stuck in a local minimum ), and you should reconsider the loss function , using softmax seems better, please correct me if i'm wrong,